# Gechazi's accursed descendants

Tags: medicine, genealogy, melachim-kings-book-of, tzaraas-negaim

Elisha cursed Gechazi with permanent Tzaares for all his generations. Is this the root of modern day Psoriasis? note the similarity in sound of illness...

Answer (score 5):

Interesting theory as to the potential translation into psoriasis, but it seems unlikely based on [Rav Hirsch](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/solomon/archives/tazria63.htm)'s challenges to those who compared tza'raas to leprosy:

> Tzaraat is not 'leprosy' as we understand it. He also demonstrates
>   that the reasons for quarantines and, in confirmed cases, exclusion
>   from the 'camp' are not to prevent the spread of disease. Among the
>   many proofs brought: if the malady covers the entire body he is clean,
>   but if the skin begins to heal he becomes a metzora. If the reason for
>   confinement was because of the danger of the disease spreading, he
>   would surely be excluded when the symptoms are most obvious!